# Automatically answer phone call on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to set up my iPhone to automatically answer phone call for me?

I work in an environment where I constantly receive a number of incoming phone calls. To make it physically less straining, I use my iPhone connected with my EarPods. It's a hassle to pick up the iPhone and slide on screen, or to reach out to press the button near microphone of my EarPods to answer the call.

I would also like to have a mechanism to configure the duration of time my iPhone rings **before** the call is automatically answered.

I generally answer **every call** that I receive, irrespective of the caller. However, it would be nice to have the ability to know the name of the caller if the caller is a contact saved in my phonebook.

I am using an iPhone 8 running iOS 12.0.1.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Is it possible to set up my iPhone to automatically answer phone call for me?

**Yes**, there is a built-in accessibility setting that you can use for **exactly** this task.

On your iPhone, in Settings app, navigate to General → Accessibility → Call Audio Routing (Last item under **Interaction** section) → Auto-Answer Calls. Tap on the switch shown against **Auto-Answer Calls** to enable it. (The setting is turned off by default)

[image]

Once enabled, you'll get the option to configure the duration of time to wait before a call is automatically answered. You can set any time interval from **0.0** seconds to **60.0** seconds in steps of **1.0** second.

---

> I generally answer every call that I receive, irrespective of the caller. However, it would be nice to have the ability to know the name of the caller if the caller is a contact saved in my phonebook.

To hear the caller name announcement, you can use another built-in setting. Go to Settings app and navigate to Phone → Announce Calls (Under **Calls** section) and select one of the available options s desired.

[image]